# Unexpected result returned by MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I ran a query on my database and found a weird behavior of sql. The returned result is not making sense to me. I have run this query and the returned result is not the desired one.

```
 SELECT MAX(marks), name FROM umer WHERE city!="NewYork"
```

Here is the snap of the table.

[image]

I am getting this result:

***Name           MAX(marks)***

eric schmidt     100

However I should be getting

*Microsoft       100*

Why is the above result is returned?

PS: The query returns correct result for `city="NEWYORK"`

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT marks, name
    FROM umer
   WHERE city != 'NewYork'
ORDER BY marks DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Your query wouldn't work because `MAX(marks)` expression and `name` column doesn't have any relation between them. So `mysql` does exactly what you required - it returns you the maximum value for the `marks` column and *some* value for `name` column.

Whereas what my query would do: it would return a single row which does not have `city` as `'NewYork'` and has the biggest `marks` value.

Comment: @Naruto: because it's the "first" row. So mysql returns the `name` for the "first" row (where "first" is usually how rows are physically stored on disk)

Comment: ok so the same logic is valid for other functions like `AVG, MIN, COUNT` etc

Comment: +1 May be worth stressing the point noted toward the end of my answer: `ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 1` will return a single record even if there are multiple records with the maximal `marks` (this may or may not be the OP's desired behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a `GROUP BY` clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL because the `name` column in the select list does not appear in the `GROUP BY`:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
>   FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
>   WHERE o.custid = c.custid
>   GROUP BY o.custid;
> ```
>
> For the query to be legal, the `name` column must be omitted from the select list or named in the `GROUP BY` clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.

In general, one must instead use a subquery to find the maximal value of `marks` and then use that to obtain the other columns of the maximal record:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     umer
WHERE    marks = (
           SELECT MAX(marks)
           FROM   umer
           WHERE  city != 'NewYork'
         )
```

Or, using a self-join:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     umer NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT MAX(marks) marks
           FROM   umer
           WHERE  city != 'NewYork'
         ) t
```

Both of the above methods will return *all records* that have the maximal marks.  If you only want a single such record, you can simply sort your filtered records and limit the results:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     umer
WHERE    city != 'NewYork'
ORDER BY marks DESC
LIMIT    1
```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a5a1/1).

Answer (score -1):

Add ORDER BY in your query becuase by default ORDER BY is ASC,
check this

```
SELECT MAX(marks), name FROM umer WHERE city!='NewYork'
ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: -1 No, `ORDER BY` takes effect *after* the results have been aggregated and therefore will have *no effect* on a resultset containing a single record.  See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/408fc/1/0).